# how to get the network throughput in sun solaris 10

Tags: solaris

I have the result of the netstat command, but am not able to figure out the throughput of the network from the server.

We are running some operations to copy to the cloud and we like to know the network throughput on the server whether it is using full 1GBPS or not.

```
# netstat -s |grep Bytes
        tcpOutDataSegs      =2357566032 tcpOutDataBytes     =2405342040
        tcpRetransSegs      =14554405   tcpRetransBytes     =968544281
        tcpInAckSegs        =2796128883 tcpInAckBytes       =1841042428
        tcpInInorderSegs    =3983264012 tcpInInorderBytes   =2643583808
        tcpInUnorderSegs    =543076533  tcpInUnorderBytes   =112312267
        tcpInDupSegs        =2939244    tcpInDupBytes       =293985883
        tcpInPartDupSegs    =668675     tcpInPartDupBytes   =432774643
        tcpInPastWinSegs    =   348     tcpInPastWinBytes   =508146615
```

Comment: If you're not allowed to install tools, tell the admins you want to see the output from [their `sar` reports](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/817-0403/spconcepts-60676.html#scrolltoc).  They *are* a professional Solaris admin shop who knows how to track performance proactively using standard Solaris tools, aren't they?  And since your process(es) are **why they exist**, they'll share performance data with you, right?

Answer (score 0):

Iperf is the standard tool here, and according to its [website](https://iperf.fr/), it works on solaris.

If there's no binary packages, you'll want to build from [source](https://github.com/esnet/iperf), which boils down to the usual `./bootstrap.sh && configure && make -j8 && su -c make install` dance.

Comment: We don't have permission to install it. So we need to find the solution from netstat only